# T-SQL Simple Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

1) How to find only those records which is having both positive and negative  quantity for example in below sample both the records for ABC which is having a positive and one negative.

```
Name   Tool   Security  QUANTITY    PRICE
  ABC      ML      XXX     100         50      
  ABC      DB      XXX    -50          50      
  XYZ      CS      YYY     30          30
```

2) How to sum up the positive and negative and make one record like

```
Name              Quantity
ABC               50
XYZ               30
```

3) Average the salary of those employees who are not managers.

```
ID  Employee    salary      ManagerID
1   ABC        300      3   
2   DEF        200      5
3   GHI        550      6
4   JKL        500      5
5   MNO        600      3
6   PQR        600      6
7   STU        550      NULL
```

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: What is the table called?

Answer (score 1):

For 1

```
select t1.* from table as t1
inner join
(
    select Name from table
    group by Name
    HAVING min(Quantity)<0 and max(Quantity)>0
) as t2 on t1.Name=t2.Name
```

Other questions are easy and put some effort

Comment: I need entire matching records not only name.

Answer (score 0):

ONE: Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

```
SELECT name, quantity
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name
HAVING MIN(quantity) < 0 AND MAX(quantity) > 0
```

TWO: Use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT name, SUM(quantity)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name
```

THREE: Use `AVG`

```
SELECT AVG(Salary)
FROM yourtable
WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
```

Comment: @Matt- First one is not working. quantity should not be part of select. Last one is not straightforward. I need avg for all the employees who are not manager, not employee who have not managers. I am able to make this up and it's not including the last item with null and if i remove the null check from subquery then it's giving me empty set-            Select avg(salary) from Employee where ID not in (select managerid from Employee where managerid is not null )